# How to access Magento Rest API with auth_key and auth_secret in Talend

Tags: api, rest, magento, talend

I want to consume Magento Rest API using Talend, I already generated oauth_token & oauth_token_secret but when i am using it with tRestClient component it is returning as 403 error code any one suggest how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think so there is option by which you can integrate magento rest api with Talend.

**Authentication**
Magento REST API uses 3-legged OAuth 1.0a protocol to authenticate the application to access the Magento service.

So For each time I think you have to authorize the application.

I think you can use Soap API or XML RPC for this.

Comment: I twisted the existing tREST component to work in Talend, and it was working fine but unfortunately we are not able to add products using Rest that is way we give up this project. Thank for your answer.

Comment: Using Oauth, but how did you use the authorization step in magento login and then authorize

Comment: that i did manually, as it require. then used credentials for further use.